# Sample random values from one raster and assign these values to a new raster

Tags: r, random, gis, raster

First I bring in my raw raster I want to randomly sample where values range from 0 - 0.8:

[image: Raster to pull a discrete distribution]

I then bring in my constant raster, where values are all 0. This raster also has a different number of columns, rows and cells compared to the raw raster:
[image]

I then want to assign random values from my raw raster to my constant raster. It should end up looking something like this:

[image]

The new raster above was created using this line:

```
values(constant_raster) <- runif(ncell(constant_raster))
```

However, instead of assigning random values from a uniform distribution, I want to assign the constant raster with random values from a discrete distribution of values based off of my raw raster.

The distribution looks like this: 
[image]

Cheers.

Comment: This question is very unclear. Perhaps you are looking for `raw_raster[] = sample(random_sample[], ncell(raw_raster), TRUE)`, but you don't specify the problem accurately at all. Btw runif draws from a uniform dist., not normal.

Comment: Made some edits there dww, hopefully that clears some things up?

Comment: In that case the code in my previous comment should work, no?

Comment: It is very close dww, but it doesn't assign values for all the cells. There are no data cells sprinkled in there. Wish I could attach a screen shot into this comment.

Comment: `constant_raster[] = sample(raw_raster[], ncell(constant_raster), TRUE)`

Comment: The above line I think is missing something. I need it to assigns those randoms values to the entire constant raster as new values.

Comment: After further thought, I think the sample function is drawing NA's from my raw raster. I will need to exclude those somehow.

Comment: `constant_raster[] = sample(raw_raster[!is.na(raw_raster)], ncell(constant_raster), TRUE)`

Comment: Please provide a self-contained example. That is, generate some example data with R code, instead of showing images. It should be a simple problem, but not easy to answer without example data.  For example, recreate your two rasters, with code like `r <- raster(xmn=1, xmx=2, ...)` etc

Comment: Thanks dww, that last line you provided does it. Alternatively I tried this but your answer is more concise.              
`random_raster_sample <- sampleRandom(raw_raster, size = 10000, na.rm = TRUE)                      
 constant_raster[] = sample(random_raster_sample[], ncell(constant_raster), TRUE)`